# Excel - Multiline Textbox offset each line onto the next column?

Tags: excel, offset, multiline

I need some Excel help here.

I am trying to create a database to store customers information in my shop.
The customer will have a name and address, something like this:

```
MR SMITH
123 FLAT A, 321 ROAD,
LONDON,
AB12 3AB
UNITED KINGDOM
```

This address has 5 rows. I want to just copy and paste everything into my userform which has a Multiline Textbox. I need it to offset each row into each column of my spreadsheet.
So it ends up looking like this:

```
CELL A1 = MR SMITH
CELL B1 = 123 FLAT A, 321 ROAD,
CELL C1 = LONDON,
CELL D1 = AB12 3AB
CELL E1 = UNITED KINGDOM
```

I know I can create a 5 single line Textboxes in my userform, but I want to save time by copying everything into 1 Textbox instead of 5.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data I have stored in the cell **H5**, but you can use a Var or a Textbox like source...
If you want to save in the cells, use:

```
Range("A1:E1").Value = Split(Range("H5").Value, Chr(10))
```

if you want an array to manipulate (put value in separate Textbox), use

```
myarr = Split(Range("H5").Value, Chr(10))
```